# UIImagePickerController Still image quality

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, resolution, autofocus

I have a problem when I take a photo programmatically with a UIImagePickerController (camera). When I touch the "Take picture" button, it freezes for half a second (measured it), then it continues. I think it is because the picture to be taken is full size, but I'm not sure. I also experience that the camera is autofocusing.

Question:
Is there a way to change camera resolution programmatically? Or is there a way to skip the autofocusing?

Thanks

**Update**: Does anyone know how can I register classes for receiving notifications when the "Switch Camera" or the "Take Picture" button is touched?

Thanks again

Comment: for receiving notification I guess you will have to create your own custom overlay view with your custom buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the quality only for the video . not for normal image capture. And also you can't turn the auto-focus. That is just the normal processing delay that you will have to bear with.